# Agrandar texto con CSS

Tags: html5, css3

¿Cómo puedo hacer para poder pasar el puntero por un texto en especifico y él aumente de tamaño?
Lo e logrado hacer con las imágenes pero con el texto no.

Este es mi código

```
<div class="Regresar"> 
  <SPAN style="position: absolute; top:300px; left:580px"> 
     <h4><a href="index.html">Regresar</a></h4> 
  </SPAN>

a:hover { color:green; transform: scale(1.15); transition: all 0.5s; }
```

Comment: Excelente si me funciono, muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 8):

Puedes hacerlo cambiado su propiedad `font-size:`

ejemplo:

```css
a { transition: all 0.5s;}
a:hover { color:green; font-size:40px;  }
```

```html
<div class="Regresar"> 
  <SPAN style=""> 
     <h4><a href="index.html">Regresar</a></h4> 
  </SPAN>
```

Comment: Normalmente aplicas la transición al elemento, en este caso `a{transition: all 0.5s};` De esta manera tienes una transición cuando entras y cuando sales. Si lo aplicas al `a:hover` tendrás una transición solo a la entrada, y un cambio brusco a la salida

Answer (score 3):

Esto ocurre porque los algunos elementos *inline* no pueden tener transformaciones, como se especifica en el [estándar HTML para la definición de `transform`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element) (traducción mía):

> **Elemento transformable**
>
> Un elemento transformable es un elemento en una de estas dos categorías:
>
> - Todos los elementos cuyo diseño está gobernado por el modelo de caja de CSS con la excepción de elementos no reemplazables de tipo inline, table-column y table-column-group,
> - Todos los  elementos pintados de SVG, el elemento clipPath y lo elementos de SVG renderizables con la excepción de cualquier descendiente de elementos de texto.

Estás intentado aplicar un `transform` a un elemento `a` que es *inline* por defecto y por lo tanto no transformable. Añádele un `display: inline-block` para que se muestre en línea pero como bloque y de ese modo ya será transformable:

```css
a:hover {
  color: green;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transform: scale(1.15);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="Regresar">
  <span style="position: absolute; top:300px; left:580px"> 
     <h4><a href="index.html">Regresar</a></h4> 
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder agrandar al texto `REGRESAR` debes aplicar el `hover` a la etiqueta `<h4></h4>` y no a la etiqueta de ancla `a`

De este modo en el CSS:

```
    h4:hover{
      transform: scaleX(3);
      transform: scaleY(3);
      transition: all 2s;
    }
```

De este modo en el HTML:

```
<div class="Regresar"> 
  <span> 
    <h4><a href="index.html">Regresar</a></h4> 
  </span>
</div>
```

Aplicamos un aumento del triple del valor original tanto para el eje X como para el eje Y; recordando que `scale()` trabaja en 2 dimensiones.

Con un resultado final como este:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        h4:hover{
          transform: scaleX(3);
          transform: scaleY(3);
          transition: all 2s;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="Regresar"> 
      <span> 
        <h4><a href="index.html">Regresar</a></h4> 
      </span>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the class put the transition and in the hover class put the change font, color, etc. No more that this =)

.myClass{transition: all 0.57;}
.myClass:hover{font-size: all 0.57;}

Comment: Buen día, estás en SO en español, por favor, traduce tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Hola Joel, mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada.Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! 
Cuando respondas al comentario de alguien, escribe "@nombreDelQueComento", para que este sea notificado.